# Code afterwards getting executed first in Firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Here is my code

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

 exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/UserRequests/{uid}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const position = snap.val();
    var loc = [position.l[0], position.l[1]];

    const db = admin.database();
    const ref = db.ref('/DriversAvailable');
    const drivers = new GeoFire(ref);
    var data = [];


    const pathId = context.auth.uid;
    const ref1 = db.ref('/UserRequests/{pathId}');
    console.log("UserID" + pathId);


    ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(function (child) {

            console.log(child.key + "  key");  //This code gets executed afterwards.

            var c = child.val();
            var aaa = child.key;
            var lat = c.l[0];
            var lng = c.l[1];


            var dist = getDistance(position.l[0], position.l[1], lat, lng);
            console.log("dis" + lat + lng + "aaa" + dist);

            data.push({
                id: aaa,
                dis: dist
            });


        });
        return console.log("gotit");
    });


    var getDistance = function (lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
        var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
        var dLat = rad(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLong = rad(lng2 - lng1);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(rad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c;
        return d; // returns the distance in meter
    };

    var rad = function (x) {
        return x * Math.PI / 180;
    };

    data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.dis - b.dis
    });

    var i = 0;
    var n = data.length;
    console.log("number" + n);    //This code is executed first.

    while (i < 2 && i <= n) {
        i++;
        var k = data[i].id;
        const getdevicetokenpromise = db.ref(`/DriversAvailable/${k}/token`).once('value');
        return getdevicetokenpromise.then(result => {
            console.log(result.val());
            var token = result.val();
            const payload = {
                data: {
                    uid: pathId
                }
            };
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
                .then((response) => {
                    return console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });
        });

    }


    console.log("hi");
});
```

I am deploying the above function in Firebase cloud. I have commented about which code is being executed first and which is executed afterwards. I couldn't get why this is happening.
The part which is executed afterwards is taking data from firebase and computing the distance between two points using the function getDistance. As it comes before the code below it, it should be executed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase works with promises, whereby the result is either resolved or rejected.
that means that the result, in your case the data fetched, takes sometime. Since your code is not nested, any other functions are executed asyncronously 
I suggest nesting what you need executed within the `.then{}` block, or decoupling the functionality and putting it in a separate function, then calling that function while passing relevant parameters, in this case the snapshot data

Answer (score 1):

The call `ref.on("value", callback)` will be executed first. The `callback` however will be executed somewhere in the future.

In you case you are probably better of using `once`:

```
ref.once('value').then(snapshot => ...)
```

All other logic should live inside the `then` as it depends on the value in the `snapshot`:

```
return ref.once('value).then(snapshot => {
  var data = []
  ...
  snapshot.forEach(child => {
    data.push(...)
  })
  ...
  // other code
})
```

Comment: I used your suggestion but it is giving me following two errors: (1) Expected catch() or return. (2) Each then() should return a value or throw.

Comment: I was able to solve the above errors but again the same thing is happening.

Comment: @GurjeetSingh please update your question to reflect the new situation.

Comment: I have updated the question with new code. I am facing the same problem even after changing the code.

Comment: you should `return` the `ref.once(...` and move all of your logic inside the `then` (see answer)